# JEST expect function toBeCalled inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a simple function which opens a new window inside setTimeout and want to test that that the window open was called.

```
export function foo() {
     setTimeout(() => {
        window.open('http://google.com');
    }, 0);
 }

describe('foo', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();
        global.open = jest.fn();
    });

    it('calls open', () => {
        foo();

        expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(global.open).toBeCalled(); //FAILING
    });
});
```

Currently my expect is failing with "Expected mock function to have been called." The mocking of the window.open looks to work ok as the test passes when I remove the setTimeout from my function.

Just wondering if anyone can steer me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try making the test case async.

Comment: I tried that but still the same failing test. Maybe my syntax is wrong?      
      it('calls open', async () => {
  foo();
  await setTimeout();
  expect(global.open).toBeCalled();

 });

Comment: Try this. `it('calls open', async() => {
  foo();
  await expect(global.open).toBeCalled();
});`

Comment: Thanks - but that didn't work

Comment: have you tried to `jest.runAllTimers()` before running checks?

Comment: yeah I tried that but doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Timers not only should be faked but also run with `jest.runAllTimers();` according to documentation at https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks like in the example below:

```
test('calls the callback after 1 second', () => {
  const timerGame = require('../timerGame');
  const callback = jest.fn();
  jest.useFakeTimers();

  timerGame(callback);

  // At this point in time, the callback should not have been called yet
  expect(callback).not.toBeCalled();

  // Fast-forward until all timers have been executed
  jest.runAllTimers();

  // Now our callback should have been called!
  expect(callback).toBeCalled();
  expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock your `global.open` and check if it was called when  `foo()` was executed:

```
it('calls open', (done) => {
        global.open = jest.fn(); // mocking global.open
        foo();  // calling foo()

        setTimeout(()=> {
          expect(global.open).toBeCalled()
          done()
        })
})
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain your answer clearly so that the OP or other users can understand your code.